# Run controller in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angularjs so i made one example to call a controller but i am not able to call controller ...

this is my sample code

```
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angularjs/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="">
    <div data-ng-controller="mycontroller">
    </div>
    <script>
        function mycontroller($scope, $http) {
            alert("alert");
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You need to use ng-app to initialise the whole app

Comment: Start with this seed project
https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fangular%2Fangular-seed&ei=uPQbVdjCAcWm8AXKhYGIBQ&usg=AFQjCNGOJHTjU7BvJmy-liHadCEbTRBDzQ&sig2=2_5hUV35UVTTBNNYLgNRyg&bvm=bv.89744112,d.dGY

Comment: @in_visible it's already used on the `body` tag

Comment: You are missing the main module also, which is reference by ng-app directive.

Comment: @Khalid it was not before, the question has been edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
<body ng-app="learning">
    <div data-ng-controller="mycontroller">
    </div>
    <script>
        angular.module("learning", [])
            .controller("mycontroller", function($scope, $http) {
                alert("alert");
            });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: but i want to do with this .is any wrong in this code

Comment: in your code (1) `ng-app=""` does not have any name & (2) global function as controller is deprecated from angular1.3

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, but I recommend you to **read** angular tutorials to understand how controllers and binds works.

http://www.w3schools.com/angular/
https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

```
<html>
<head>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp"> 
    <div ng-controller="mycontroller" ng-init="initMethod()">
        <!--<input type="text" ng-model="test"></p>
        <div>{{test}}</div>-->
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('mycontroller', function($scope) {
        alert("alert")

        $scope.initMethod = function(){
            alert("alert from init");
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ya it's good but i want  to know that  what mistake am i doing ?

Comment: You need declare a app (ng-app binding) in the document and then add the controller to the app.
For ng-init binding is just a alternative to initialize your code instead of write directly in the controller